# If I run a SQL statement multiple times with row limit, will I get the same result each time?

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

Given my statement stays the same. Given there are 15000 available rows, but I do a row limit with `rownum` Will I get the same output each and every time?

Example SQL I'm using:

```
SELECT distinct 
     TO_CHAR(S.DID), 
     TO_CHAR(S.DPERMCONTAINER), 
     S.DBARCODE, 
     S.DMEDIATYPE, 
     S.DDOCTITLE, 
     S.XCOMMENTS, 
     rm.xcategoryid, 
     s.xdivision, 
     S.XPROJECTNAME, 
     S.XLEGACYPROJECTNAME,
     S.XLABELNOTE, 
     S.XPROJECTENDDATE, 
     S.XEVENTDATE 
FROM 
     PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMS S 
     left join prd64_urmserver.extitemsrm rm on s.did = rm.did 
WHERE 
     S.DMEDIATYPE = 'Folder' 
     AND S.DPERMCONTAINER IN
          (SELECT distinct TO_CHAR(S.DID)
          FROM PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMS S 
          left join DIDV V on s.did = v.did 
          left join prd64_urmserver.extitemsrm rm on s.did = rm.did
          WHERE v.did IS NULL
               and RM.xDerivedIsFrozen = '0' 
               AND s.dmediatype = 'Box' 
               and S.XLABELNOTE = 'DISP: GPO-CRM-US-ATT-20160415-09' 
               and s.xprojectenddate < to_date('05/25/2006', 'mm-dd-yyyy') 
               and rownum <= 5000)
UNION
(SELECT distinct 
     TO_CHAR(S.DID), 
     TO_CHAR(S.DPERMCONTAINER), 
     S.DBARCODE, 
     S.DMEDIATYPE, 
     S.DDOCTITLE, 
     S.XCOMMENTS, 
     rm.xcategoryid, 
     s.xdivision, 
     S.XPROJECTNAME, 
     S.XLEGACYPROJECTNAME,
     S.XLABELNOTE, 
     S.XPROJECTENDDATE, 
     S.XEVENTDATE
FROM 
     PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMS S 
     left join DIDV V on s.did = v.did 
     left join prd64_urmserver.extitemsrm rm on s.did = rm.did
WHERE 
     v.did IS NULL 
          and RM.xDerivedIsFrozen = '0' 
          AND s.dmediatype = 'Box' 
          and S.XLABELNOTE = 'DISP: GPO-CRM-US-ATT-20160415-09' 
          and s.xprojectenddate < to_date('05/25/2006', 'mm-dd-yyyy') 
          and rownum <= 5000);
```

Please let me know if I can be any more detailed.

Comment: `Will I get the same output each and every time?` no

Comment: order by rows are not guaranteed unless you explicitly order them in query

Comment: also the order by needs to be unique to each row, so if you order by some id and have 2 records with same id those records might flip positions.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you add `ORDER BY` clauses so the results are always in the same order.  Otherwise the results are returned in non-deterministic order, often as the result of index usage or statistics.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So in theory, if I `ORDER BY S.DID ASC` then I should get the same result consistently?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, assuming no new records are added or removed

Comment: according to [Ask Tom](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html) even with an order by you aren't guaranteed the same result set because of the order oracle evaluates the query. Check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37473109/1264335) for how to guarantee consistent results.

Answer (score 2):

You will not get the same rows each time according to [Ask Tom](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html). Even with an order by you will not. rownum is evaluated before the rows are ordered.  If you want the same rows each time it needs to be ordered in a subquery:

```
select * from 
(
SELECT distinct 
     TO_CHAR(S.DID), 
     TO_CHAR(S.DPERMCONTAINER), 
     S.DBARCODE, 
     S.DMEDIATYPE, 
     S.DDOCTITLE, 
     S.XCOMMENTS, 
     rm.xcategoryid, 
     s.xdivision, 
     S.XPROJECTNAME, 
     S.XLEGACYPROJECTNAME,
     S.XLABELNOTE, 
     S.XPROJECTENDDATE, 
     S.XEVENTDATE 
FROM 
     PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMS S 
     left join prd64_urmserver.extitemsrm rm on s.did = rm.did 
WHERE 
     S.DMEDIATYPE = 'Folder' 
     AND S.DPERMCONTAINER IN
          (SELECT distinct TO_CHAR(S.DID)
          FROM PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMS S 
          left join DIDV V on s.did = v.did 
          left join prd64_urmserver.extitemsrm rm on s.did = rm.did
          WHERE v.did IS NULL
               and RM.xDerivedIsFrozen = '0' 
               AND s.dmediatype = 'Box' 
               and S.XLABELNOTE = 'DISP: GPO-CRM-US-ATT-20160415-09' 
               and s.xprojectenddate < to_date('05/25/2006', 'mm-dd-yyyy') 
 order by ...)
where rownum <= 5000
UNION
select * from 
(SELECT distinct 
     TO_CHAR(S.DID), 
     TO_CHAR(S.DPERMCONTAINER), 
     S.DBARCODE, 
     S.DMEDIATYPE, 
     S.DDOCTITLE, 
     S.XCOMMENTS, 
     rm.xcategoryid, 
     s.xdivision, 
     S.XPROJECTNAME, 
     S.XLEGACYPROJECTNAME,
     S.XLABELNOTE, 
     S.XPROJECTENDDATE, 
     S.XEVENTDATE
FROM 
     PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMS S 
     left join DIDV V on s.did = v.did 
     left join prd64_urmserver.extitemsrm rm on s.did = rm.did
WHERE 
     v.did IS NULL 
          and RM.xDerivedIsFrozen = '0' 
          AND s.dmediatype = 'Box' 
          and S.XLABELNOTE = 'DISP: GPO-CRM-US-ATT-20160415-09' 
          and s.xprojectenddate < to_date('05/25/2006', 'mm-dd-yyyy') 
order by ...)
where rownum <= 5000;
```